# reading a dutch 'slimme meter' has USB troubles

Tags: usb

In the Netherlands the energy providers are rolling out smart meters which allow you measure your energy usage in your house. There's a cable that you need to buy ([this one](https://www.sossolutions.nl/slimme-meter-kabel)) but you should be able to plug it into the raspberry and read from it.

There's one small problem. When I try to read the USB, I get nothing back. This yields nothing now:

```
head -27 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

When I run that the bash script just hangs there. It is strange because it was running yesterday just fine. It would return a blob of text just like:

```
/ISK5\2M550E-1012

1-3:0.2.8(50)
0-0:1.0.0(181005125307S)
0-0:96.1.1(4530303433303037313335303636383138)
1-0:1.8.1(000005.811*kWh)
1-0:1.8.2(000014.353*kWh)
1-0:2.8.1(000000.000*kWh)
1-0:2.8.2(000000.000*kWh)
0-0:96.14.0(0002)
1-0:1.7.0(00.227*kW)
1-0:2.7.0(00.000*kW)
0-0:96.7.21(00011)
0-0:96.7.9(00003)
1-0:99.97.0()
1-0:32.32.0(00000)
1-0:32.36.0(00002)
0-0:96.13.0()
1-0:32.7.0(236.1*V)
1-0:31.7.0(001*A)
1-0:21.7.0(00.227*kW)
1-0:22.7.0(00.000*kW)
0-1:24.1.0(003)
0-1:96.1.0(4730303339303031383136373038353138)
0-1:24.2.1(181005125001S)(00003.957*m3)
!E278
```

I've reinstalled the raspberry from scratch but to no avail. I've also replaced the cable but to no avail.

Comment: What are the permissions of `/dev/ttyUSB0`? Do the logged in user have to be in a specific group? Watching permanent with `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0` and power cycle the smart meter does not give anything, not even some glitches?

Comment: even with that `sudo` command added i see nothing.

Comment: after `ls -lhat` i see `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Oct  6 15:12 /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: but i am logged in as root, so i think that that shouldn't be it.

Comment: Never login as root for normal work on unix systems. Login as normal user, e.g. user **pi**, add this user to group `dialout` (`sudo adduser pi dialout`), logout and login and check again.

Comment: `The user `pi' is already a member of `dialout'.` no dice unfortunately

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `dmesg` right after you plug in the cable?

Answer (score 0):

USB RS232 converters are often hogged by the USB modem facilities. That's why they are in the `dialout` group after all. Check if you have a modem manager or similar software running, and stop it. It's a race for the ressource, that's why it sometimes work and sometimes not.

If you want to run both a modem manager (e.g. for an USB connected LTE modem) and your meter, you have to avoid the modem software recognize your smart meter as a modem. I usually do it by creating an UDEV rule for the vendor:device USB id of the "special" converter and have it appear as /dev/myspecialdevice instead of /dev/ttyUSB*.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I am very much new to rpi. How can I check if a modem manager is running (or turn it off)?

Comment: It's may be process called literally *ModemManager*. Use `ps aux` or `top` to identify it and kill it. If your own program runs nicely, you have the culprit. If you don't need it, simply deinstall.

Comment: I cannot find such a service that is running either via `ps aux`, `top` or `systemctl`

Comment: Try `sudo fuser /dev/ttyUSB0` then.